PWM 12V fans connected directly to PCIe 8pin GPU cable
I have a custom-made server with many HDDs and fans. Motherboard has not got enough headers to feed all fans, not to mention these headers have usually just 12V @ 1A limit. Some server MBs even have 2-3A.

https://noctua.at/en/na-fc1
I have bought fan controllers with 3A limit. It can easily handle the large, or high-speed fans. Problem is feeding this controller. I never run full speed, but once you forget...bye bye MB header.
Unfortunately, PSU SATA cables are all used by HDDs, so there is no option to feed these fans with SATA power supply.

https://www.akasa.co.uk/update.php?tpl=product/product.detail.tpl&model=AK-CBFA08-30BK
I also bought splitters/extenders, but that is the same issue, just without regulation.
It makes me wonder if I can simply cut off the 4 pin PWM connector, and solder it directly to PCIe 8pin GPU cable?

PCIe standard reference
8pin GPU cable has got 3x 12V @ ~4A (cable is officially 150 W or 12V @ 12.5A).
Is there any risk of fire or meltdown?
Or do I need to design some kind of PCB? That was my idea as well. Design a PCB with many 3-4pin PWM headers, and hook them to PSU PCIe GPU cables because there is always enough 12V capacity, but lack of connectivity.

David Hajes - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add each webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More site rules in the [tour] & [help]) TY

David Hajes - Thanks for adding the required references for two of the three copied images. However the reference text "PCIe standard reference" needs to be improved for the 3rd copied image. Please link to the source where you copied that image from. TY

There is no more risk than connecting to the sata connector, which likely goes to the same or at least an equivalent 12v power supply rail. Essentially you're doing the same thing just with a different wire.
As for fire, I have seen electrical fires started by badly made hard drive power cables shorting. You have the same risk here, so take appropriate care that you do not short anything given that your supply can likely source tens of amps. Fuses wouldn't be a bad idea as well.

SATA cables are dangerous, and people abuse them. In crypto paranoia many kids were burnt...literally ;-) They have something like 1A per pin, and easily burn. I don't like to use them.
Peripheral cables are different cables with just 75W limit or about 4.5A per cable split to 4 connectors max.
You mean like a fuse for each header? Let's say I connect 10 PWM headers per PCIe cable - each header own 2A fuse or so, please?

2A fuse per line is a good idea so that if a wire pulls out you don't burn.
